# CSS - advanced item background

Tags: css, background, background-image

I want to create an item (a link) that will have inner shadows on both sides (left and right) and the rest of the item will be transparent.

It should look something like this:

[image: image with inner shadows]

The point is I don't know how wide my link will be so I need something like:

```
background: url(left-shadow) left center;
background: url(right-shadow) right center;
```

But for one element. Any ideas how to achieve that?

You guys are totally right about multiple backgrounds, but they're not supported even in IE8:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multiple_backgrounds.html

So maybe something else? I forgot to mention that I want my solution to be working at least in IE8 (and would be perfect to see it working in IE7 also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use the css "Sliding Doors"  it adds a bit of markup overhead but will work nicely for this scenario until the CSS3 multiple background stuff becomes more widely supported.

You can read up on it here:  [A List Apart "Sliding Doors" technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 supports multiple backgrounds, with the following syntax:

```
background: url(left-shadow) left center,
            url(right-shadow) right center,
            url(bottom-shadow) center bottom;
```

Comment: @Wordrocessor: no it won't work in the older IEs (8 and below)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm this is really interesting! I would suggest you add three backgrounds.

```
background:url(bottom-shadow) left bottom, url(left-shadow) left center, url(right-shadow) right center;
```

The bottom shadow should include the gray-white gradient too. Notice the commas between each background.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Inner Shadow with Example

```
.innerShadow_css
{
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 11px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 11px #000000;
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 11px #000000;
}
```

http://discoverweb.info/css-inner-shadow.html